# write access violation using 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, char

I'm trying to put characters into my 2D array. i've defined these objects:

```
typedef struct board {
char* board[25][80];
}Board;

typedef struct obstacleA {
int* x;
int* y;
}ObstacleA;

typedef struct obstacleC {
int* x;
int* y;
}ObstacleC;

typedef struct obstacleB {
int* x;
int* y;
}ObstacleB;

typedef struct Star {
int *x;
int *y;
int *power;
}Star;

typedef struct Cross {
int *x;
int *y;
int *power;
}Cross;
```

and my spawn function gives random numbers(or coordinates) to my objects

```
void spawn(Board* board, Cross* cross, Star* star, ObstacleA* A, ObstacleB* B, ObstacleC* C) {

srand(time(NULL));

cross->x = (1 + rand() % 24);
cross->y = (1 + rand() % 79);

star->x = (1 + rand() % 24);
star->y = (1 + rand() % 79);

A->x = (1 + rand() % 24);
A->y = (1 + rand() % 79);

B->x = (1+ rand() % 24);
B->y = (1+ rand() % 79);

C->x = (1 + rand() % 24); 
C->y = (1 + rand() % 79);

putBoard(&board, &cross, &star, &A, &B, &C);
}
```

and the putBoard function puts the characters in the proper coordinates:

```
void putBoard(Board* board, Cross* cross, Star* star, ObstacleA* A, ObstacleB* B, ObstacleC* C) {

board->board[*star->x][*star->y] = '*';
board->board[*cross->x][*cross->y] = '+';
board->board[*A->x][*A->y] = 'A';
board->board[*B->x][*B->y] = 'B';
board->board[*C->x][*C->y] = 'C';
}
```

however, Upon running the program, i get an "Exception thrown: write access violation.
board was 0x21C3BD2."
at the line "`board->board[*C->x][*C->y] = 'C';`".

Comment: Do you really want a 2D array of `char` *pointers*?

Comment: Allocate memory so that those `char*` points to some memory and you write to them. `&board` can't have the type `Board*` if `board`  itself is `Board*` - it will be `Board**`.

Comment: @coderredoc or just assign to _string_ literals

Comment: same thing for integers in structures. I think you don't need pointers at all in your structs.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre.: Yes assign to string literal and don't try to modify it then. (to @OP)

Comment: And if you only use the first element of e.g. `star->x`, then why use pointers to begin with? Why is the `x` member of the `Star` structure a pointer?

Comment: Why's everything a pointer? Just remove all those `*`s.

Comment: You have undefined behavior here - trying to modify some memory that is not your own.

Comment: Why have three diffferent _types_ for things that are the same? All your `obstacles` are the same type, so use only one type!

Comment: and `star->x = (1 + rand() % 24);` is wrong because `x` is a _pointer_ to an int. Remove the `*` in the typedefs!

Answer (score 2):

When you call `putBoard` you pass a pointer *to the pointer* to the board. That is, you pass something of type `Board **`. Same with the other arguments you pass to `putBoard`, you are passing pointers to the pointers.

Don't use the address-of operator `&` when calling `putBoard` from `spawn`.

A good compiler should have warned you about passing incompatible pointer types.

And as the comments say, you have gone way overboard with the pointers. In most places where you use pointers, you probably don't need it at all.

Comment: Yes, i shouldn't have used that many pointers. the program works fine now, thanks@

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning random values to the addresses, this is not what you wanted:

```
cross->x = (1 + rand() % 24);
cross->y = (1 + rand() % 79);

star->x = (1 + rand() % 24);
star->y = (1 + rand() % 79);

A->x = (1 + rand() % 24);
A->y = (1 + rand() % 79);

B->x = (1+ rand() % 24);
B->y = (1+ rand() % 79);

C->x = (1 + rand() % 24); 
C->y = (1 + rand() % 79);
```

Since you have a random value in the `x`, `y` pointers, you have two problems in the line where the program crashed:

```
board->board[*C->x][*C->y] = 'C';".
```

1) Dereferncing a random address will typically crash the program.

2) Even if your program survives that operation the derefernced values

```
*C->x, *C->y
```

can be easily outside the boundaries of the `board` array.  That can crash your program too.

You definitely overuse pointers in your structures. You do not need them.
All you should care is to pass the pointers to the your structures so internal members can be modified.

3) The program should be as simple as possible, the overuse of pointers makes it harder to understand and error prone.

```
   putBoard(&board, &cross, &star, &A, &B, &C);
```

Should be:

```
   putBoard(board, cross, star, A, B, C);
```

As stated, compiler should have warned you about passing incompatible pointer types.

Your program could be fixed with your structures but simpler is always better.
Take a look at:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

#define ROWS 6
#define COLUMNS 50 

typedef struct board {
    char board[ROWS][COLUMNS];
}Board;

typedef struct obstacleA {
    int x;
    int y;
}ObstacleA;

typedef struct obstacleC {
    int x;
    int y;
}ObstacleC;

typedef struct obstacleB {
    int x;
    int y;
}ObstacleB;

typedef struct Star {
    int x;
    int y;
    int power;
}Star;

typedef struct Cross {
    int x;
    int y;
    int power;
}Cross;

void putBoard(Board* board, Cross* cross, Star* star, ObstacleA* A, ObstacleB* B, ObstacleC* C) {

    board->board[star->x][star->y] = '*';
    board->board[cross->x][cross->y] = '+';
    board->board[A->x][A->y] = 'A';
    board->board[B->x][B->y] = 'B';
    board->board[C->x][C->y] = 'C';
}

void spawn(Board* board, Cross* cross, Star* star, ObstacleA* A, ObstacleB* B, ObstacleC* C) {

    srand(time(NULL));

    cross->x = (1 + rand() % (ROWS-1));
    cross->y = (1 + rand() % (COLUMNS-1));

    star->x = (1 + rand() % (ROWS-1));
    star->y = (1 + rand() %  (COLUMNS-1));

    A->x = (1 + rand() % (ROWS-1));
    A->y = (1 + rand() %  (COLUMNS-1));

    B->x = (1+ rand() % (ROWS-1));
    B->y = (1+ rand() %  (COLUMNS-1));

    C->x = (1 + rand() % (ROWS-1)); 
    C->y = (1 + rand() %  (COLUMNS-1));

    putBoard(board, cross, star, A, B, C);
}

void printBoard(Board* board)
{
    for(int i= 0; i< ROWS; i++){
        for(int j= 0; j< COLUMNS; j++) {
            printf("%c", board->board[i][j]);    
        }
        printf("\n");     
   }
}

void cleanBoard(Board* board)
{
    for(int i= 0; i< ROWS; i++){
        for(int j= 0; j< COLUMNS; j++) {
            board->board[i][j] = ' ';    
        }
   }
}

int main(void)
{
    Board board;
    ObstacleA A;
    ObstacleC C;
    ObstacleB B;
    Star S;
    Cross CR;

    cleanBoard(&board);

    spawn(&board, &CR, &S, &A, &B, &C);
    putBoard(&board, &CR, &S, &A, &B, &C);

    printBoard(&board);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
                                      C           
                                *                 
            A                                     
   +                                              
                                        B
```